# Traduction de « opdreunen »

Tags: vocabulaire, néerlandais

J’ai besoin d’aide pour trouver une traduction. On l’utilise pour décrire que quelqu’un lit quelque chose *à haute voix*, ou dit quelque chose qu’il connait par cœur. J’ai même du mal à trouver une traduction littérale. C’est pourquoi je tente d’esquisser son emploi à court d’un mot à remplacer. Voici des renseignements circonstanciels :

- Le mot s’applique si une suite de mots, d’aliments requis pour faire un repas, de travaux ou d'autres choses semblables est prononcée. Il peut s’agir de quelque chose qu’on se rappelle facilement, ou d’un écrit.
- Le mot est seulement utilisé quand celui qui parle ne bégaie pas. Il prononce tout à une vitesse continue, et sur un ton neutre. Il parle plutôt lentement que vite.
- Le mot comporte aussi des sous-entendus. Il laisse penser que le locuteur trouve agaçant de dire ce qu’il dit; il est peut-être ennuyé. Le meilleur cadre pour son emploi est à l’école où des enfants apprennent des conjugaisons à contrecœur.

Quel mot français utiliseriez-vous ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On peut utiliser réciter (ou pour s'approcher plus du sens de votre mot "réciter d'une voix monocorde"), ou psalmodier (qui a cependant une connotation religieuse, mais peut justement être utiliser pour indiquer une récitation mécanique, presque "fanatique") ou encore marmonner dans certains cas.

Par exemple, on peut dire :

> - Il/Elle récite son cours
> - Il/Elle récite une recette de cuisine
> - Il/Elle marmonne sa liste de course
> - Il/Elle psalmodie ses formules mathématiques
> - Il/Elle récite son poème d'une voix monocorde

Comment: +1 pour réciter, mais je pense que marmonner est tout à fait inadapté ici.

Answer (score 2):

Le premier mot qui me vient à l'esprit pour traduire l'agacement et l'ennui engendré par la récitation mécanique de quelque chose appris par cœur, comme justement une table de multiplication ou une conjugaison, est *litanie*.
Le sens premier de [litanie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litanie) est religieux,  c'est une prière liturgique de forme populaire.  Mais il est aussi employé au sens figuré pour parler d'une énumération longue, ennuyeuse et répétitive.

Mais il n'existe en français aucun verbe forgé à partir de ce mot.<sup>1</sup> Bien sûr on peut toujours néologiser et, même s'ils ne trouvaient pas le mot joli ou s'en offusquaient, la plupart des français comprendraient :

> Les élèves *litanient leurs conjugaisons.

Diverses possibilités s'offrent à nous :

> Les élèves récitent leurs tables de multiplications comme une litanie.<sup>2</sup>
>
> La maîtresse s'endormait au son de la litanie des tables de multiplication égrenée par ses élèves.

L'utilisation du verbe *égrener* renforce l'idée d'ennui. *Égrener*, au sens figuré c'est « faire entendre des mots, un à un, de façon détachée ».

D'ailleurs on peut très bien utiliser le verbe *égrener* tout seul.

> Les élèves égrènent leurs tables de multiplications.

Je préfère l'emploi de « comme une litanie » pour traduire l'idée que tu demandes, mais si tu veux un mot unique *égrener* peut convenir.

<sup>1 *Litanier* existe en tant que nom : c'est un recueil de litanies.</sup>
<sup>2 *Réciter* tout seul ne suffit pas car ce verbe est trop neutre et n'implique ni l'ennui ni la monotonie réclamée dans la question.</sup>